# clear Interval not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this is my controller:

```
  .controller('mainController', function($http, $scope, $timeout, $sce, updateService) {
      updateData = function() {

          updateService.getDataA($http, $scope);
          updateService.getDataB($http, $scope, $sce);
      }
      var updateIntervalId = setInterval(updateData, 1000);
  })
```

Now when the user refreshes the page old requests are still being made, and I tried to cancel it by putting this under the interval call:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    console.log('interval killed');
    clearInterval(updateIntervalId);      
}
```

the console is logging 'interval killed', so its being executed, but requests are still being made, why?

Comment: With `var updateIntervalId`  you _bind_ the variable `updateIntervalId`  to the scope of the callback function `function($http, $scope, $timeout, $sce, updateService) {`  so it is not accessible from  your `onbeforeunload` callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us do the **angular way**

Inject `$interval` service in your controller

And update your code to following

```
var intervalPromise = $interval(updateData, 1000);

$scope.$on('$destroy', function() { // Gets triggered when the scope is destroyed.
     $interval.cancel(intervalPromise );
});
```

And remove `window.onbeforeunload` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to angularJS I would always recommend to use [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) to handle intervals, since it works better with the angularJS hidden mechanics.

Then if the event `window.onbeforeunload` lies outside the controller, you will never be able to access `updateIntervalId` since it lies inside another scope, hence you should make it global.

Comment: It would be better to not use `window.onbeforeunload` anyway because `onbeforeunload`  could be changed by any other code so it is not reliable. It would be better to use `window.addEventListener("beforeunload", ...)` and place that right after the `var updateIntervalId = setInterval(updateData, 1000);`

Comment: You are completely right, I was just pointing out that the problem might have been different scopes!